# update column of a collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update extra columns in collection. Say I have a collection as

```
db.collection.find()
{_id:....,name:niren,Range1:10,Range2:30}
```

Now I want to update extra columns as

```
db.collection.update({name:"niren"},{Range3:50,Range4:70})
```

but this is not working since it is for update existing record. Any help?

Comment: Just a reminder to accept the answers to your questions. Your history shows you have only ever accepted answers twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator:

```
db.collection.update({name:"niren"},{ "$set": { Range3:50,Range4:70 }})
```

This allows you to modify the document without overwriting the existing document content entirely.