# MongoDb's $ (update) does not update array's element but rather replace it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to *update an element of an array* inside mongodb's document (I am using mongoose). Schema is something like:

```
{
 ..
 arr : [{
  foo: Number,
  bar: [String],
  name: String
 }]
 ..
}
```

And my query is:

```
SomeModel.update({
 _id: "id of the document",
 arr: {
  $elemMatch: {
   _id: "_id assigned by mongoose to array element"
  }
 }
}, {
 'arr.$': {
  name: 'new name'  
 }
}).exec()
```

It just replaces whole array element say:

```
{
 _id: "some objectId",
 name: 'old name',
 foo: 0,
}
```

to:

```
{
 name: 'new name'
}
```

what I want:

```
{
 _id: "some objectId",
 name: 'new name',
 foo: 0,
}
```

What I am curious to know if it is possible to achieve this in *single update query* ? (May be there is a silly mistake in my query :P or another approach)

I would also like to do update query like so:

```
{
 $inc: { foo: 1},
 $push: { bar: "abc"}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [update column of a collection in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054268/update-column-of-a-collection-in-mongodb)

Comment: Also for reference, the `_id` value inside the array is not produced by MongoDB but is rather set by Mongoose. MongoDB itself only assigns a unique `_id` value for the top level document. The behavior can be disabled in mongoose, but it is the current default.

Comment: Yes my bad changed mongodb to mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still struggling with the whole implementation the full application of your statement is as follows:

```
SomeModel.update(
    {
        "arr._id": "123"
    },
    {
        "$set": { "arr.$.name": "new name" },
        "$inc": { "arr.$.foo": 1},
        "$push": { "arr.$.bar": "abc" }
    }
)
,function(err,numAffected) {

});
```

So each operation is performed in turn.